# Access storage account using private IP when using private endpoint

Tags: azure, azure-storage

I followed instructions as per https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/private-link/create-private-endpoint-storage-portal

Weirdly the blob GET requests only seem to work when using FQDN and not the direct private IP.

The private IP assigned to mystorageaccount.blob.core.windows.net is 10.0.0.5

GET requests to https://mystorageaccount.blob.core.windows.net/samplecontainer/1.png and https://mystorageaccount.privatelink.blob.core.windows.net/samplecontainer/1.png both work without issues and both get mapped to remote address 10.0.0.5:443

However, GET request to https://10.0.0.5/samplecontainer/1.png gives a 400 - Bad Request - Invalid Hostname error.

Comment: Is there anything you do not understand? Please let me know if you have any questions. And if it solves your problem please accept it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As I know, even if you access the Storage account without a private endpoint to download the blob, you also cannot use the IP address. Azure needs to resolve the blob endpoint via the domain name.

For the private endpoint for the storage account, the [private link](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/storage/common/storage-private-endpoints#dns-changes-for-private-endpoints) is also set by Azure. And the private IP address just provides a tunnel to connect the storage from the VNet. So you can access the storage blob via the domain name of the storage blob or the private link, but private IP address not.